# Looping over option menu selenium in python

Tags: python, loops, selenium

My code uses selenium to go select options from a drop down menu. I have a code that looks just like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.website.com")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='idname']/option[text()='option1']").click()
```

This works just fine. But there are many options in the drop down menu and I wish to loop over all items in the drop down menu. I prepared the following code to loop over the options:

```
options = ["option1", "option2"]
for opts in options:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='idname']/option[text()=opts]").click()
```

This does not work. Any suggestion on how to get such a loop to work? Something I do not understand about loops in python?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you.  The code will

- Find the element
- Iterate to get all the options from the dropdown
- Iterate through the list
- For each item in the list, select the current option
- It's necessary to re-select the dropdown on each pass, as the web page has changed

Like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.website.com")

select = browser.find_element_by_xpath( "//select[@id='idname']")  #get the select element            
options = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list

optionsList = []

for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
    optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

for optionValue in optionsList:
    print "starting loop on option %s" % optionValue

    select = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath( "//select[@id='idname']"))
    select.select_by_value(optionValue)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna have the time to try this tonight. I'll make sure to mark this question as answered.

Comment: The answer above works with a couple of small corrections. "/option[text()='option1'" should be deleted in the two places it appears and "self.br.find_element_by_xpath" should be "browser.find_element_by_xpath".