# Scrapy, python+selenium. Errors in the information gathered from the page

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, scrapy

Hi everyone and I need your support!
I have some page([here](http://colombo.in.ua/colombo-design/ruchka-colombo-gira-jm11.html)) and try scrapped it. On page there dropdown menu and options in dropdown menu change information on page(For changes options I using selenium). I'm trying to iterate select options(i found example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691943/looping-over-option-menu-selenium-in-python)) and gather information from the page after the update, but in output file i had 4 identical value(as if options do not change). Selenium right iterate options(I saw it) and i dont know what i do wrong.
Here my code:

```
from colombo.items import ColomboItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

class ColomboSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'ColomboSpider'
    allowed_domains = ["http://colombo.in.ua"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://colombo.in.ua/colombo-design/ruchka-colombo-gira-jm11.html",
    ] 

    def __init__(self):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        # use any browser you wish
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox() 

    def __del__(self):
        self.browser.close()

    def parse(self, response):

        self.browser.get(response.url)
        #let JavaScript Load
        time.sleep(3) 

        optionsList = []# options attribute value
        dropdown = self.browser.find_element_by_id("jshop_attr_id13")#my dropdown element name
        options = dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
        for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
            optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

        hxs = Selector(response)
        items = []

        for optionValue in optionsList:
            select = Select(self.browser.find_element_by_id("jshop_attr_id13"))#i found dropdown
            select.select_by_value(optionValue)#and i click on n-value in my list
            time.sleep(2)
            firm_list = hxs.xpath('.//div[@class="jshop productfull"]/form[1]')
            for sel in firm_list:
                item = ColomboItem()
                item['price']=sel.xpath('.//span[@id="block_price"]/text()').extract()
                item['name']=sel.xpath('.//h1/text()').extract()
                items.append(item)
        return iter(items)
```

What i had in output file:

```
1929.61 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
1929.61 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
1929.61 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
1929.61 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
```

But, right output is

```
1929.61 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
2275.21 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
2456.66 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
2966.42 грн Ручка Colombo GIRA JM11
```

Thanks for answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am skipping the text part, but this code will work for amount part

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import os
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from random import randint
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import autoit

class SprintTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):       
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://colombo.in.ua/colombo-design/ruchka-colombo-gira-jm11.html")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_input(self):
        dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_id("jshop_attr_id13")
        options = dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
        for option in options:
                a = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block_price"]')
                b=a.text
                a = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jshop_attr_id13"]').click()
                print b
                autoit.send("{DOWN}{ENTER}")
                time.sleep(2)


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Output is:

```
1929.61 грн
2275.21 грн
2456.66 грн
2966.42 грн
```

Comment: sry but ubuntu hasnt autoit

Answer (score 0):

I m sorry for loong time answer:

```
from colombo.items import ColomboItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

class ColomboSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'ColomboSpider'
    allowed_domains = ["http://colombo.in.ua"]
    start_urls = [

    ] 

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()


    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):

        self.driver.get(response.url)
        #let JavaScript Load
        time.sleep(3) 
        try:
            optionsList = []# options attribute value
            dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_id("jshop_attr_id13")#my dropdown element name
            options = dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
            for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
                optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))


            #hxs = Selector(response)
            items = []

            for optionValue in optionsList:
                select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("jshop_attr_id13"))#i found dropdown
                select.select_by_value(optionValue)#and i click on n-value in my list
                time.sleep(2)
                item = ColomboItem()
                item['price']=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block_price"]').text
                item['name'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//h1').text
                options_value = self.driver.find_element_by_id("jshop_attr_id13")
                for option in options_value.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
                    if option.get_attribute("value") == optionValue:
                        item['color'] = option.get_attribute("innerHTML")
                items.append(item)
            return iter(items)

        except Exception:
            items = []
            item = ColomboItem()
            item['price']=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block_price"]').text
            item['name'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//h1').text
            items.append(item)
            return iter(items)
```

output is

```
Chromo - Хром   3333.53 грн     Ручка Colombo DEA FF21 (Код: FF21) 
Chromat - Матовый хром  3817.33 грн     Ручка Colombo DEA FF21 (Код: FF21)
```