# I am trying to scrape this website for all of the documents that are produced from the drop down forms

Tags: python, web-scraping

The [site](https://www.cpms.osd.mil/Subpage/AFWageSchedules/) I am trying to scrap has drop-down menus that end up producing a link to a document. The end documents are what I want. I have no experience with web scraping so I don't know where to start on this. I don't know where to start. I have tried adapting [this](http://toddhayton.com/2015/12/11/iterating-through-dynamic-select-options-with-selenium/) to my needs, but I couldn't get it working. I also tried to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691943/looping-over-option-menu-selenium-in-python).

I know basically I need to:

```
for state in states:
    select state

    for type in types:
        select type
        select wage_area_radio button

            for area in wage_area:
                select area

                for locality in localities:
                    select locality

                    for date in dates:
                        select date
                        get_document
```

I just haven't found anything that works for me yet. Is there a tool better than Selenium for this? I am currently trying to bend it to my will using the the code from my second example as a starter.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your coding skills and knowledge of HTTP, I would try one of two things. Note that scraping this site appears slightly non-trivial because of the different form options that appear based on what was previously selected, and the fact that there's a lot of AJAX calls happening.

1) Follow the HTTP requests (especially the AJAX ones) that are being made in something like Chrome DevTools. You'll get a good understanding of how the final URL is being formed and how to construct it yourself. In particular, it looks like the last POST to AFWageScheduleYearSelected is the one that generates the final url. Then, you can make these calls yourself in a Python HTTP library to get the documents.

2) Use something like PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) which is a headless browser. I don't have experience scraping with Selenium, but my understanding is that it is more of a testing/automation tool. In any case, PhantomJS is pretty easy to get up and running and you can basically click page elements, fill out forms, etc.

If you do end up using PhantomJS (or any other browser-like tool), you'll run into issues with the AJAX calls that populate the forms. Basically, you'll end up trying to fill out forms that don't yet exist on the page because the data is still being sent over the network. The easiest way to get around this is to just set timeouts (of say 2 seconds) in between each form field that you fill out. The alternative to using timeouts (which may be unreliable and slow) is to continuously poll the page until the AJAX call is finished.